# Can i get a record while pattern matching on its contents?

Tags: haskell, record

Basically, i want to pattern match on the contents of a record, and then return a modification of said record. So i have this sort of situation cropping up a lot:

```
updateChr :: Database -> Database -> Database
updateChr db Database{mode=1, characters=chr} = db{characters=(map someFunc chr)}
updateChr db Database{mode=2, characters=chr} = db{characters=(map someOtherFunc chr)}
```

Where the two Database arguments should always be the same record. Is there a way i can do this while only passing the record once?

Comment: Do you just want `db@Database{...}`, i.e. as-pattern?

Comment: Also, if you move to lens, you could do something like `updateChr db = characters %~ (modeToFunc $ db ^. mode) $ db`. I'd say you should write `modeToFunc` anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use an [*as pattern* [Haskell-report]](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html):

```
updateChr :: Database -> Database
updateChr db@Database{mode=1, characters=chr} = db {characters=(map someFunc chr)}
updateChr db@Database{mode=2, characters=chr} = db {characters=(map someOtherFunc chr)}
```

If you however always want to map the `characters`, you can here make use a guard:

```
updateChr :: Database -> Database
updateChr db@Database{mode=m, characters=chr} = db {characters=map f chr}
    where f | m == 1 = someFunction
            | otherwise = someOtherFunction
```

Comment: Thanks, the former is exactly what i was looking for, and i have a few places where the latter might be better.